# Downloading cn1lib in IntelliJ does not work

Tags: java, intellij-idea, codenameone

Have downloaded some cn1libs using Codename One Preferences. The lib folder now contains 2 files per cn1lib eg.

- CN1CircleProgress.cn1lib
- CN1CircleProgress.ver

When *Refresh cn1libs* is activated and it shows *Invoked ant target: refresh-libs* for a short while. The class are not available. 
Have tried ide restart and adding the lib folder codename one libraries classes path without success. Any suggestions?

Iam using IntelliJ Community Edition 2016.3.1, JRE 1.8.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried this myself and it works just fine for me you would see the library in the completion and build process but won't see it in the standard IDE module system.

Comment: Nothing is stated in the end of the build process. The prompt just dismisses

Comment: In IntelliJ you see a tree UI when building which is a bit useless. Turn it to the text output by unchecking that button on the top left part of the console then try sending a build.

Comment: Thanks Shai.
Somehow ant was not working from ide and a complete reinstall fixed the issue.